# How to have multiple context menus using WxFormBuilder with WxWidgets in Python

Tags: python, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I am using WxFormBuilder to create code for a WxWidget-based application in Python 3.9.  I would like to have two distinct popup (context) menus, but I have been unable to get WxFormBuilder to let me create a second popup menu with different menu items.  (I could, of course, put the context menu items from both popups into a single popup and de-enable those that are not relevant, but this still means a cluttered and confusing context menu and makes for messier code.  I'd prefer to avoid this.)

(1) Is there a way to get WxFormBuilder to support (or at least peacefully co-exist with) two separate popup menus?

(2) Is there a way to programatically *hide* (not simply gray out) items in a popup menu?

Comment: I don't know about 1, but if you look at the documentation for wxMenu, you will find the answer: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_menu.html#ad0478a386aa0f55b568686fc8837d00e

Comment: @Igor Thanks! Will Delete() remove the item only from the current instantiation?

Comment: yes. - Try it and you will see.

Comment: @Igor I tried some experiments and it appears to permanently delete the item so that it's also gone from subsequent instantiations, also.  Remove() will also remove it, but in a way where a later Append() should be able to re-add it. (Haven't tried this yet, but the doc says so.) This is pretty ugly though and I would have to write a class to manage popup state. Looks like I'm faced with a choice between uglinesses!

Comment: IIUC, you were initially wanted 2 different context menu. Why do you want to re-add something after deletion?

Comment: I'd like to show a different context menu depending on what part of the GUI the user clicks. I can't control that, so if the menus are A and B, the sequence might be ABBAABABBB (or whatever). If I delete a B-only menu item for the first click, I'll have to re-add it for the second click.  I guess I'll just go with the somewhat confusing graying out of irrelevant items.

Comment: @MarkOlsdon, why? You can just create a menu and add appropriate options in the context menu handler. You do know what object the click was done, right? I have it the same way in my program... You will just add the submenus dynamically.